# Pip install does not fetch the latest version

Tags: python, django, pip, froala

I want to install the latest `django-froala-editor` version.

But `pip install` keeps installing the `django-froala-editor` version 2.0.1.

#### Steps to reproduce the problem.

(using virtualenvwrapper to ease the test)

```
mktmpenv
pip search froala
pip install django-froala-editor
```

The version `2.0.1` gets installed, even though the `2.3.2` is [present on the pypi website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-froala-editor) and the pip search shows a `2.1.0` version.

[image: screen shot 2016-06-13 at 10 40 41]

#### OS.

OS X Yosemity 10.10.5,
pip version 8.1.2,
python 2.7

Comment: please do this. `pip install django-froala-editor==2.3.2`

Comment: I get `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-froala-editor==2.3.2 (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.8.7, 0.9.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.3.1, 1.2.3.2, 1.2.4, 1.2.4.1, 1.2.4.2, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc3.post1, 2.0.1)
No matching distribution found for django-froala-editor==2.3.2`

Comment: Also, make sure that you are using the latest pip version (``pip install pip --upgrade``).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install directly from `git` if you can't get the latest version from pypi:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor
```

This can be included in your requirements.txt as `git+https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor`

Generally,

```
pip install git+{url to repo}
```

Comment: Works well. Do you know if this can work on a django requirements.txt file ?

Comment: Yep, add `git+https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor` to your `requirements.txt`

Comment: Thanks, I found out that you can specify the version from the release pages: https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor/archive/2.3.2.zip.
If you want to add it on your answer I'll accept it.